# How does __slots__ avoid a dictionary lookup?

Tags: python, slots, python-internals

I've heard that `__slots__` makes objects faster by avoiding a dictionary lookup. My confusion comes from Python being a dynamic language. In a static language, we avoid a dictionary lookup for `a.test` by doing a compile-time optimisation to save the index in the instruction we run.

Now, in Python, `a` could just as easily be another object that has a dictionary or a different set of attributes. It seems like we'll still have to do a dictionary lookup - the only difference seems to be that we only need one dictionary for the class, rather than a dictionary for each object.

With this rational,

1. How does `__slots__` avoid a dictionary lookup?
2. Does slots make accessing objects faster?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`__slots__` does not (significantly) speed up attribute access:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('spam',)
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.spam = 'eggs'
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.spam = 'eggs'
... 
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('t.spam', 'from __main__ import Foo; t=Foo()')
0.07030296325683594
>>> timeit.timeit('t.spam', 'from __main__ import Bar; t=Bar()')
0.07646608352661133
```

The goal of using `__slots__` is to *save memory*; instead of using a `.__dict__` mapping on the instance, the class has [descriptors objects](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for each and every attribute named in `__slots__` and instances have the attribute assigned *wether or not* they have an actual value:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('spam',)
... 
>>> dir(Foo())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'spam']
>>> Foo().spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: spam
>>> Foo.spam
<member 'spam' of 'Foo' objects>
>>> type(Foo.spam)
<type 'member_descriptor'>
```

So python still has to look at the class for each attribute access on an instance of `Foo` (to find the descriptor). Any unknown attribute (say, `Foo.ham`) will still result in Python looking through the class MRO to search for that attribute, and that includes dictionary searches. And you can still assign additional attributes to the *class*:

```
>>> Foo.ham = 'eggs'
>>> dir(Foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'ham', 'spam']
>>> Foo().ham
'eggs'
```

The slot descriptors are created when the class is created, and access memory assigned to each instance to store and retrieve a reference to the associated value (the same chunk of memory that tracks instance reference counts and a reference back to the class object). Without slots, a descriptor for `__dict__` is used accessing a reference to a `dict` object in the same manner.

Comment: *"not significantly"*? 10% improvement for a single line change is quite significant in my book.If you understand `__slots__`'s obscure side-effects, of course :)

Comment: See also: [`http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532903-how-__slots__-are-implemented/`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532903-how-__slots__-are-implemented/)

Comment: For the curious: if you don't use `__slots__` and instead declare the member at the class level, you'll see a speed _penalty_ of about 5% over the plain non-slots version.

Comment: With instantiation the difference becomes (unsurprisingly) wider with non-slots version being almost 50% slower:

   
`>>> timeit.timeit('Foo().spam', 'from __main__ import Foo;')
    0.33598813007120043
   >>> timeit.timeit('Bar().spam', 'from __main__ import Bar;')
   0.49041724496055394`

Comment: Guido (the guy who created \_\_slots\_\_ and Python in general), explicitly states that he created \_\_slots\_\_ for the purpose of reducing access time to attributes by avoiding the class dictionary lookup needed to check for descriptors before any attribute is accessed. See the \_\_slots\_\_  section on his blog here: https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html

Comment: @MatviyKotoniy: Guido initially came up with the idea for `__slots__` to counteract the expected performance hit introduced by the checks for descriptors, but that turned out to *not be an issue.* As stated in that same blog post: *This turned out unnecessary, but by that time it was of course too late to remove `__slots__`. Of course, used properly, slots really can increase performance, **especially by reducing memory footprint when many small objects are created.*** (bold emphasis mine).

Answer (score 8):

It might speed up a program where you instantiate *lots* of objects of the same class, genuinely never change what attributes they have, and cache misses on all those duplicate dictionaries present a real performance problem.

This is really just a special case of the general situation where saving space *sometimes* saves time as well, where cache is the limiting factor.

So, it probably won't make accessing *one* object faster, but may speed up accessing *many* objects of the same type.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/212858).