# Why can using __slots__ make attribute access faster?

Tags: python, slots

This question: [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) answers that `__slots__` can make attribute access faster. But I want to know why?

What happens when we define `__slots__` in a class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118564/how-does-slots-avoid-a-dictionary-lookup

Comment: `__slots__` is an optimisation feature which does away with the `__dict__` dictionary - hence the optimisation.  
It has a number of disadvantages.  It has to be constructed and maintained 'manually', whereas `__dict__` is dynamic.  Second, inherited classes must use it as well, otherwise they might be slower.  Thirdly, it breaks code that expects there to be a `__dict__`.

Answer (score 4):

As for *why* **access** is faster Guido [talks about it here](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html):

> In particular, in order to make data descriptors work properly, any
>   manipulation of an object's attributes first involved a check of the
>   class dictionary to see if that attribute was, in fact, a data
>   descriptor. If so, the descriptor was used to handle the attribute
>   access instead of manually manipulating the instance dictionary as is
>   normally the case. However, this extra check also meant that an extra
>   lookup would be performed prior to inspecting the dictionary of each
>   instance. Thus the use of `__slots__` was a way to optimize the lookup
>   of data attributes—a fallback, if you will, in case people were
>   disappointed with the performance impact of the new class system.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation ([slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)):

> By default, instances of both old and new-style classes have a dictionary for attribute storage. This wastes space for objects having very few instance variables. The space consumption can become acute when creating large numbers of instances.
>
> The default can be overridden by defining `__slots__` in a new-style class definition. The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.

Using `__slots__` gives memory and performance optimizations.