# isinstance and abstract base class

Tags: python, abstract-base-class

I'm trying to check if an object has a method `start` and a method `update`.
I thought I could use abstract base class, just like `collections.abc.Iterable` work.

In my case I cannot do `class Foo(Interface)` since `Foo` is load dynamically, and have no access to `Interface`.

What is the idiomatic way to check if an object have specific methods ?

```py
import abc


class Interface(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def start():
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def update():
        pass


class Foo:
    def start():
        pass

    def update():
        pass


def main():
    foo = Foo()
    print(f'{isinstance(foo, Interface) = }')  # False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268404/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-if-a-class-has-a-function-defined

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the methods of a class or class instance by doing `dir(foo)`. This will return you a list of all methods available for this class or instance. You can then check if methods `start` and `update` are inside this list by doing `"start" in dir(foo) and "update" in dir(foo)`

Note, that `dir` will also show you all of the class variables and properties, so you might not want to use it.

You can read more about this topic [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python)